# how dependency injection makes testing easier?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

i read so many articles regarding di ,but there are no proper examples to understand in terms of testing.

i think so many developers don't have idea on usage of di in magento2.
anyone give one example testing with and without di.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html